# Terraform recognizing changes made outside terraform for Cloud Run

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform0.12+

I have downloaded & reusing **terraform-google-cloud-run** module from official github repo & I have added the below lifecycle block in module.

This module will be used to create cloudrun using TF & for subsequent deployments I am using gcloud run deploy command.

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      metadata[0].annotations,
      template[0].metadata[0].annotations,
      template[0].metadata[0].name,
      status[0].latest_created_revision_name,
      status[0].latest_ready_revision_name,
      template[0].spec[0].containers[0].image
    ]
  }
```

When I run the plan having some later changes to other resources I am getting as below

```
Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform
Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the
last "terraform apply" which may have affected this plan:
  # module.cloud_run_service["project-1"].google_cloud_run_service.main has changed
  ~ resource "google_cloud_run_service" "main" {
        id                         = "locations/europe-west4/namespaces/project-1/services/api-service"
        name                       = "api-service"
      ~ status                     = [
          ~ {
              ~ latest_ready_revision_name   = "api-service-qmkbv" -> "api-service-00007-wuz"
                # (4 unchanged elements hidden)
            },
        ]
        # (3 unchanged attributes hidden)
        # (3 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }
```

I have added the **latest_ready_revision_name** to ignore but then too I am facing this issue while updating some different resource through TF

How do I ignore this ?

Comment: In recent Terraform versions Terraform shows the "Objects have changed outside of Terraform" messages only if the set of proposed actions includes something that seems (to Terraform's heuristic) like it was caused by the change outside of Terraform. Therefore I think the answer to this will depend on what else is included in the plan alongside this message: Terraform seems to think that one of your other changes is related to the cloud run service, and so it's presenting this as additional context that might be relevant to reviewing the proposed changes.

Comment: Can you share the other changes in your plan as part of your question? That might help me or someone else to identify what is activating Terraform's heuristic and possibly suggest a different way to write it to avoid the false positive.

Comment: `ignore_changes` is for ignoring differences between the desired state and the actual state, and not for ignoring changes made outside of Terraform. Terraform cannot ignore changes made outside of Terraform because they are not under Terraform's control.

Comment: @MartinAtkins, If there is no changes in plan then TF wont show this Note, but when I tried adding resource such as a google_storage_bucket or any other like BigQuery then I am getting this note in the plan. 

For cloud run we have frequent deployment & many different services which will deploy through gcloud command & every time if TF shows this then it may reflect & confuse other people, thats where I am worried.

Comment: I have below versions set
```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    google = {
      source  = "hashicorp/google"
      version = "~> 4.47.0"
    }
  }
  required_version = "~> 1.3.6"
}
```

Comment: If the new resource you are adding includes references that include the items that are changing outside of Terraform then Terraform will show the note to illustrate how the change made outside of Terraform might affect how the new resource will be created. If Terraform is correct that the two are related then what you described is the intended behavior and you can't disable it. If Terraform is showing this even though there seems to be no relationship between the new resource and this existing resource then that might be fixable by describing it differently, but will need to see more to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add this code in resource "google_cloud_run_service" "main":

```
traffic {
    percent         = 100
    latest_revision = true
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but I think we can't ignore the note saying changes made outside terraform. May be I will give it a try one more time as you suggest & get back if this works.